# moderncv babel english,greek issue

Tags: babel, moderncv, greek

I am using babel in moderncv to switch languages between greek and english, although it recognises greek language (after adding some extra lines of code with the help of site [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265938/moderncv-and-babel-greek-cause-missing-endcsname-error/272764?noredirect=1#comment655452_272764)), when I'm trying to switch to english , i get an error.

For example, i try to switch in english in order to fill in my email by inserting in the code the line \selectlanguage{english} and i get the following error :

[image]

The Error , a few lines, in code, later :

[image]

the code is here :

```
   %% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% provide an expandable version of \roman
\newcommand{\exproman}[1]{\romannumeral\csname c@#1\endcsname}
% patch the commands in moderncv that use \roman
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\collectionadd}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\collectionadd}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\makeatother

% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

\usepackage{import}

% personal data
\name{Sonoma}{'epithet}
\title{Biografik'o Shme'iwma}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{dress,tk}{}{}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+30 756567565}           % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\phone[fixed]{78678678686}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}                      % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{\selectlanguage{english}myname@hotmail.co.uk}                              % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.myname.webs.com}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\extrainfo{additional information}                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                       % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
%\quote{Some quote}                                 % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{[\arabic{enumiv}]}% CONSIDER REPLACING THE ABOVE BY THIS

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\small{Undergraduate electrical and electronic engineer completing the final year of a master's degree. Passionate about science, with strong technical, business, and interpersonal skills for working in a team and successfully completing a project.}



\end{document}


%% end of file `template.tex'.
```

Any ideas how to fix that ?

Comment: Why do you have to show such a long example? Are all the items needed to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: i just wanted to explain it because i don't know what should be important or not to post ..

Comment: Do you really believe that a `\section{Previous Employment}
`  could be important?. Nobody expect from you to remove everything that is irrelevant, but you could make at least an effort and remove obviously unneeded lines.

Comment: i just wanted to be completed and fully working because i don't know where it should be exactly the issue.. anyway ill make a try..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put the language switch in the `\email` command as its argument is used for a link. But you can inject it in the symbol before the link:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\name{Sonoma}{'epithet}
\title{Biografik'o Shme'iwma} 
\address{dress,tk}{}{}% 
\email{myname@hotmail.co.uk}                
\homepage{www.myname.webs.com}              
\moderncvstyle{banking}  
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd\emailsymbol{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}
\xapptocmd\homepagesymbol{\selectlanguage{english}}{}{}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ohh nice thanks a loot !!! And from now and on if i want to switch languages for example in education section i can, by simple adding the \ selectlanguage ?

Comment: Yes normally it should work fine.