# ModernCV babel and bold text issue

Tags: babel, moderncv, bold, greek

i had an issue with moderncv and greek language  so a user told me to add these lines in my code ([see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265938/moderncv-and-babel-greek-cause-missing-endcsname-error))

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
% provide an expandable version of \roman
\newcommand{\exproman}[1]{\romannumeral\csname c@#1\endcsname}
% patch the commands in moderncv that use \roman
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\collectionadd}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\collectionadd}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\makeatother
```

But since then i can't bold some headlines, for example my name or Education,Experience etc.. When i bold them , nothing happens, i do not get an error but the text do not get bold either.. Any ideas about that ?

for example :

```
%% start of file `template.tex'.
%% Copyright 2006-2013 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% provide an expandable version of \roman
\newcommand{\exproman}[1]{\romannumeral\csname c@#1\endcsname}
% patch the commands in moderncv that use \roman
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\endcvcolumns}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\cvcolumn}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\collectionadd}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\collectionadd}{\roman}{\exproman}{}{}
\makeatother


% modern themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
%\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

\usepackage{import}

% personal data
\name{\textbf{test}}{text}
```

Comment: Please always add a complete example to a question. Don't let us hunt down various questions to assemble it.

Comment: When i add \textbf{text} i do not get warning or error but the text do not get bold !! Do you want to add all the code? Have my personal info in it now :P

Comment: just updated my first post with a 2nd code. its the first lines of the code , at the end of it is the \textbf{} i said about

Comment: @ALdaperan The addition is useless, as a `document` environment is missing.

Comment: i finally found the solution. The problem was that although i was using greek language i did not use greek font. So i found a greek font named kerkis and installed it and everything is ok :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op solved the problem by her/his own. Because a mwe is missing other people can't recreate the errror and solution.