# moderncv and Greek babel problem

Tags: babel, moderncv, greek

I am working on overleaf and I have an issue when using moderncv and greek using the babel package.

The following code shows the problem. I compile with pdfLaTeX. If I uncomment any of the mobile, fixed or fax lines the code does not compile. The error is the same as in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265938/moderncv-and-babel-greek-cause-missing-endcsname-error) question, but the proposed solution does not work for me. If I uncomment the mobile, fixed or fax lines and also delete the T1 in fontenc, the code compiles and produces a correct PDF. The point is that I need the T1, because I have small parts of text in English throughout my CV and, most importantly, there is a bibliography section that should also appear in English. If I remove the T1, everything written in Latin characters appears in the corresponding Greek characters.

Any idea how to correct the problem?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[orange]{classic}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

\firstname{Ιωάννης}
\familyname{Παπαδόπουλος}
\title{Η δουλειά μου}
\address{Η διεύθυνση μου}
%\phone[mobile]{0000000000}
%\phone[fixed]{5555555555}
%\phone[fax]{9999999999}
\email{venetis@unipi.gr}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moderncv.cls` uses `\roman{<counter>}` for defining internal commands, but this fails when `babel-greek` is loaded, because it changes `\roman` to something not expandable.

Restore the standard definition.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[orange]{classic}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

\makeatletter
\def\@roman#1{\romannumeral#1}
\makeatother

\firstname{Ιωάννης}
\familyname{Παπαδόπουλος}
\title{Η δουλειά μου}
\address{Η διεύθυνση μου}
\phone[mobile]{0000000000}
\phone[fixed]{5555555555}
\phone[fax]{9999999999}
\email{venetis@unipi.gr}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

I suggest to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with `fontsetup`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[orange]{classic}
\usepackage{fontsetup}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}


\firstname{Ιωάννης}
\familyname{Παπαδόπουλος}
\title{Η δουλειά μου}
\address{Η διεύθυνση μου}
\phone[mobile]{0000000000}
\phone[fixed]{5555555555}
\phone[fax]{9999999999}
\email{venetis@unipi.gr}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Both solutions you proposed work!